# ASP.NET MVC3 Integration with Microsoft Office (Word)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ms-word

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 Application, And I have a form where it generates an output form. Currently I generate the output form in an html file, but I want to switch it to generate it as a Microsoft Word Document, or essentially populate a word template. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Nothing out of the box, generate manually or use a third party tool. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2991751/368552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several components that allow you to generate a word document programmatically. The one I've had the most success with is [Syncfusion DocIO](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/reporting/docio) It's a paid utility but worth the price if you need to manipulate word documents programmatically. If cost is an issue, there are tutorials on how to build a [server-side document generation utility using Open XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb735940%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: I had a quick question, when dealing with this problem, would  having the server-side dealing with it be the only solution? Would I be able to have the client-side deal with it?